# Substring subquery format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, substring

I am having a rough time to get the substring qry format
Can some help me on how the substring should be written

```
select tagname, padname = 1, datetime, (select value        
 from analoghistory where tagname = 'tata' +   
 substring(a.tagname, 6, 2) + 'lastpart' and datetime = 
 a.datetime) as value

 from DiscreteHistory a
  where tagname in ('Name here')
  and datetime >= {ts '2017-11-01 07:45:00'}
  and datetime <= {ts '2017-11-10 15:48:00'}
  and wwresolution = 60000
  and value = 1
  order by tagname, datetime
```

I appreciate the assistance 
Thanks

Comment: I am using mssql server 2014.

Sorry left that out..

Thanks

Comment: what problem did u have?